# Font size for ToC entries in Powerdot

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, powerdot

Any way to change the font size globally in the on the slide table of contents?
When I use `paper = smartboard`, the ToC entries on the left of the page are really small.
I can do it by slide but that is a pain.